# Variable value is null (expected !=null)

Tags: apex

I cannot catch this issue's solution: (I try to simplify the context) :

In the first method the value of q.Id is lost, so the debug gives NULL

HERE I POST THE VF PAGE (named ManualBilling

```
<apex:page standardController="Fattura__c" extensions="InvoiceManager">
<apex:form> 
    <apex:Messages/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Informazioni sul preventivo di questa trattativa da fatturare">  
        <apex:pageBlockSection>             
            <apex:outputText value="{!q.Name}">
            </apex:outputText>          
        </apex:pageBlockSection>            
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Fatturazione" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <!--  
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.Opportunity__c}"/> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.AccountId__c}"/>   
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.ContactId__c}"/>   
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.Data_di_Scadenza__c}"/>    
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.Tipo_Pagamento__c}"/>  
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.Importo_Preventivo__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.Note__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Fattura__c.Status__c}"/>      
             -->                        
        </apex:pageBlockSection>        

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Salva" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Annulla" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>    
        <apex:pageBlockSection>             
        </apex:pageBlockSection>                
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

HERE'S THE METHODS  (InvoiceManager.cls)

```
public Quote getq() {

           system.debug(q.Id);  --> it gives null! 
        return [SELECT Id,Name from Quote where Id=:q.Id];
    }

public pageReference switchBilling() {


   o = [SELECT Id from Opportunity WHERE Id =: rowId];
   q = [SELECT Id,Name,AccountId,ContactId,GrandTotal,Tipo_Pagamento__c from Quote WHERE OpportunityId =: o.Id];

    if(q.Tipo_Pagamento__c!='[011] RID BANCARIO - RATE') {


        return autoBilling(q,o);
    }

    else {

        system.debug(q.id) ---> HERE GIVING RIGHT ID!
        return new pageReference('/apex/ManualBilling');        


    }

}
```

Comment: How do you call this two methods ?

Comment: the second is used for binding the values of the Quote from a VF page..but it doesn't work.. while the first method is called from other methods..I hope this informations can be enough

Comment: post your page too please

Comment: this seems related to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51172/how-to-correcly-bind-object-field-from-the-controller-to-the-vf-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have the query separated out in 2 methods, I am **assuming** that you must be calling getq() method from your page like {!q} to get the quote name and id. You need to call the method1() before calling getq() for the query to execute. Easy fix

```
public Quote getq() {
        method1();
        system.debug(q.Id);  --> it gives null! 
        return [SELECT Id,Name from Quote where Id=q.Id];
}
```

Comment: I posted all code..

Answer (score 1):

I would of expected a NullPointerException rather than null but the reason is because `switchBilling` is initialising the `q` variable but `getq` could get called before the `switchBilling` method has been called, which would cause `q` to be null.

You could change how you get the `q` variable so that it's not dependent on `switchBilling` being called first. The code below will do the SOQL query to get `q` the first time it is referenced (i.e. lazy loaded).

```
public Quote q {
    get { 
        if (q == null) {
            q = [SELECT Id,Name,AccountId,ContactId,GrandTotal,Tipo_Pagamento__c from Quote WHERE OpportunityId = :o.Id];
        }
        return q;
    }
    set;
}
```